# Org-mode export bold text to beamer

Tags: beamer, org-mode

When exporting an org file to beamer, the *bold* text syntax is translated as \alert{bold}, which gives text in red color. How do I get actual bold text instead?

Comment: You can add bold text with `\textbf{bold}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries}
```

to tell beamer to display alerted text in bold

Answer (score 0):

You can change the behavior of org-mode export by using `#+BIND` variables. The concept is outlined in the [Advanced Export Configuration](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html) section of the org-mode manual.

First, you create a function that replaces every occurrence of `\alert` with `\textbf`:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun org-beamer-bold-as-textbf (s backend info)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\alert" "\\\\textbf" s))
#+END_SRC
```

Then, you use `#+BIND` to add this function as a filter for bold elements:

```
#+BIND: org-export-filter-bold-functions (org-beamer-bold-as-textbf)
```

Note that the variable org-export-allow-bind-keywords has to be non-nil in order for the `#+BIND` command to work.